# "UNIQUE constraint failed: users_user.username" error?

Tags: django

I'm studying user registration with Django, but I don't know why I get this error: **UNIQUE constraint failed: users_user.username** after trying to fill in the form. I have deleted the database and every migration/cache. It's with a custom user model where I use email as identifier.

Is there something wrong with the code below, or do you have any suggestions?

views.py

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'users/registration.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = '/'
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2',)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Epostadresse',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    veri_mail = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: This is because you defined `username` field as `unique` in  model.py

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Ah, that's correct! Why can't it be unique?

Comment: @Alasdair I updated the question with models.py now

Comment: When I remove unique I get this error in console: users.User: (auth.E003) 'User.email' must be unique because it is named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Comment: Are you trying to save more users with the **same email**? Is that you want?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge No, I want it to be unique and only create one user. Is it trying to create two users at the same time? I thought i fixed that with the meta class.

Comment: This error is raising when you tries to create a new  `User` instance with email as `my@email.com`, but In your DB there is already a `User` instance with the same `email` value.(`my@email.com`) ('my@email.com' is only an example)

Comment: To solve this error, you have to provide different email value while User creation (also you could catch the exception and show it as a message in your form)